# Number of subgroups of order $2^n$ in the powerset equipped with symmetric difference

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite set. We define $\mathcal{P}(X)$ to be the power set of $X$ and $A \mathbin{\Delta} B$ to be the symmetric difference $A \mathbin{\Delta} B = (A \cup B)\setminus(A\cap B).$ I'm aware that $G_X = (\mathcal{P}(X), \Delta)$ forms an abelian group, with identity element $\varnothing$ and each element being self-inverse. I further understand by Lagrange's theorem that as $|\mathcal{P}(X)| = 2^{|X|},$ we have that any subgroup of this group must have order which is a power of 2. My goal is to find the number of subgroups of $G_X$ with order $2^n$ in terms of $|X|$ and $n$.

I've tried a combinatorial argument, but I think I'm overcounting and can't figure out where. If $H \leq G$ has order 4, then $H = \{\varnothing, A, B, A \mathbin{\Delta} B\}$ equipped with the symmetric difference, for some sets $A,B \in \mathcal{P}(X).$ However, simply specifying each element via "choose $A,B$ in $\mathcal{P}(X)$" leads me to an answer of $\binom{2^{|X|}}{2} = (2^{|X|-1})(2^{|X|}-1).$ This severely overcounts, however: letting $X = \{0,1\}$ yields that there are 6 subgroups of $G_X$ with order $4$. Yet $G_X$ itself has order 4, so this seems horribly wrong. Am I thinking of this in the wrong way? Any ideas on an overall formula? I figure this combinatorial argument (done right) can generalize to arbitrary orders of $2^n$, but as it stands it's pretty bad.

Thanks for your time! I'm relatively new to abstract algebra, so any guidance in the right direction will be quite helpful.

Comment: Do you know of any groups that $P(X)$ is isomorphic to?

Comment: On first glance, it looks like since each element of $P(X)$ is its own inverse we may say that $P(X)$ is isomorphic to the direct product of $2^n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ under pointwise addition mod 2. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $P(X)$ is the vector space of dimension $m=|X|$ over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. You want to find the number of subspaces of dimension $n$, that is the number of linearly independent subsets of $n$ vectors divided by the order of $GL_n(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ (we need to take into account that several sets of l.i. vectors may span the same subspace, $|GL_n(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)|$ is the number of bases of the $n$-dim space over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$).

To build a linearly independent subset $e_1,...,e_n$ we can pick non-zero $e_1$ arbitrarily - $2^m-1$ options, then pick $e_2$ arbitrarily, except it should not belong to $span\{e_1\}$, $2^m-2$ options, then pick $e_3$ only making sure it is not in $span\{e_1,e_2\}$, $2^m-4$ options, and so on. Altogether the number of choices is $(2^m-1)(2^m-2)\cdot ...\cdot (2^m-2^{n-1})$. Denote it by $u_{m,n}$.

Every matrix in $GL_n(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)$ has $n$ linearly independent row-vectors. So the number $|GL_n(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)|$ can be computed the same way as $u_{m,n}$, it is equal to $v_n=(2^n-1)(2^n-2)\cdot...\cdot (2^n-2^{n-1})$.

So the number you are interested in is $u_{m,n}/v_n$.

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}).$ However, that expression $v_n = (2^n-1)(2^n-2)\cdots(2^n-2^{n-1})$ seems familiar. It's the number of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, right? Is $GL_n(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ the set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices (under matrix multiplication) with entries in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}?$ If so, why is its order equal to the number of bases?

Comment: You are right. These matrices form a group, the general linear group of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, denoted by $GL_n(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z).$ But the fact that it is a group is not important here.

Comment: "If so, why is its order equal to the number of bases? " For every basis  $v_1, \dots , v_n$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} )^n$, you have a map from the standard basis $e_1, \dots e_n$ to that basis via $e_1 \mapsto v_1, e_2 \mapsto v_2$, and so on. This map extends to an invertible linear operator (i.e a matrix). Moreover, for any invertible matrix $A$, there is a basis gotten by $A(e_1), \dots A(e_n)$.

Comment: @markvs Ah, I see. I was going to ask you why its order is equal to the number of possible bases of an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but I think I’ve just understood it. Each element of the group is just a way of compacting $n$ linearly independent row vectors, and then it all follows from there. Huh - pretty neat.

Comment: @DionelJaime Yep! This makes sense - I think I just had that same realization right as you posted this.